# Do something or To do something?

Tags: prepositions, difference, phrase-usage

Consider a simple to-do list:

- To make exercises.
- To call Jane.
- To buy wine.

or

- Make exercises.
- Call Jane.
- Buy wine.

Which version is correct/better? Does they have a difference in their meaning?

Edit: I don't ask about how to write to-do lists. The metaphor of to-do list is used just for convenience. I ask about the difference in the *meaning* of these short sentences.

Comment: You can write your own to-do list however you wish. However I use the style in the second example. It's just a list of things, like a shopping list. Here you write "Buy wine" as one job to do, but on the shopping list itself you would write "Wine" because it is a shopping list, and so you know it lists things you need to buy. Similarly, this is a to-do list, so you know it contains jobs to do.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is just an example. Of course, I can write it in any way. I can even draw the images. But I want to understand the difference between proposed examples.

Comment: I don't think anyone would write it the first way, it doesn't seem right. This [blog](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/02/infinitive-2.html) says *When “to” appears with an infinitive, it is generally referred to as an “infinitive marker” or “infinitive particle”; it is not part of the verb and is not always used.*.

Comment: There's no need to use the word "to" here in the context of a to-do list.  However, you need to use the verb "do" with exercises.  You can't really "make exercises". That doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate form is the imperative, so there would be no "to". But the audience of a to-do list is generally yourself, so grammar isn't really important.

Also, with "to", these aren't sentences, they are noun phrases. A sentence requires a finite verb, and putting "to" means that it's the full infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

Since the **title** reads *to-do list,* there is ***no*** difference between the two sets of 'to-dos'. Anyone *able to fog a mirror* would understand that these are the tasks/jobs to be done, and it is a list of them.

So, to answer, *there is no difference* because the context is clear. Secondly, you can write the way you want. However, I'd prefer the second list to avoid redundancy. It's already *to -do* list ...so I'd simply write the task rather adding *to* again.